# Advice on OpenGL 2.1

Tags: opengl, 3d, java, jogl

I'm looking to finally get into OpenGL to bring some game ideas of mine to life! As I want to aim for lower class systems I'm probably looking at OpenGL 2.0/2.1 using JOGL (as I know Java the best).

Could anyone suggest some good books or resources as the books I have found so far talk about OpenGL 3 or 4! I read that the OpenGL Superbible is a good book and it seems the fourth edition covers OpenGL 2, can anyone recommend this? Obviously I would have to convert the examples in any book to use JOGL as I assume most books are C/C++.

I know I probably should be learning 3 or 4 as there are lots of changes, but I'm not looking for cutting edge graphics, just simple things (plus I would like to port to Mac / Linux as it is Java).

Comment: I'm not sure why people aren't commenting, but I can tell you why they're down voting. If you hover over the down vote button, you'll see that it says "This question does not show any research effort...", which yours does not. Additionally, this site is for real answerable questions, not discussions about what books would be best. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what kinds of questions are a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a game engine. You very likely won't wan to start with straight up gl. It will take for ever to actually see anything, on top of the fact that you will have a lot of rewriting to do for sequels. Look at [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) or something similar.

Here is a list of engines (not exclusive to java).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Answer (score 1):

I've had horrible performance experiences with JOGL, LWJGL always performed better, was more consistent, and reliable (also more actively developed).